# How to take accent in account on centos [6|7] in bash

Tags: bash, locale, unicode

I'll give you an exemple, it would help.

on my ubuntu LTS 18.04

```
touch /tmp/"Éléments supprimés" 
ls -l /tmp/*suppr*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 USER USER 0 mars   4 08:28 '/tmp/Éléments supprimés'
```

on my centos 6 or 7 (same problem)

```
touch /tmp/"Éléments supprimés" 
ls /tmp/*supprim*
/tmp/??l??ments supprim??s
rm /tmp/*supprim*
rm: remove regular empty file `/tmp/\303\211l\303\251ments supprim\303\251s'? ^C
```

How can I make centos behavior like Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it's a matter of locale, simply put (with the right locale for you)

```
export LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

and then the file get created accordingly with the command line.

Comment: `LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8` would be better IMHO. `LC_ALL` includes a lot of things that _you_ may want (eg. `LC_COLLATE` completely mystifying any glob ranges and sorted listings, `LC_NUMERIC` changing the output of `printf`, etc), but a casual reader certainly does NOT.